# How to Properly Parse a CSV File to Work With SVG Elements

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm working with Javascript and d3.js for the first time and as a nice starter project I wanted to make a bar chart. It went fine but the array I used was declared within the .js file, instead of actually being imported from a separate file.
I am trying to retrofit my code so that it pulls the data from a CSV file instead of just declaring an array within the actual .js file, however the CSV method converts each row into an object which throws off how my code works with the data and I'm not sure how to fix it.  Is there a way to pull an array out of a CSV or am I better off changing everything in order to work better with the d3.csv() method?

So far my attempt was just wrapping the whole .js function in the d3.csv(/Data/data.csv, function(dataset){...}, I also made sure that all the values that were numerical were converted to numbers with a forEach loop.

```
d3.csv("Data/data.csv", function(dataset){
  dataset.forEach(function(d){
    d.year = +d.year;
    d.reported = +d.reported;
    d.crude = +d.crude;
    d.ageAdj = +d.ageAdj;
  });
  ...some example code that I believe is affected by the error...
   svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x",(d)=>(xScale(d[0])))
    .attr("y",(d)=>(yScale(d[2])))
    .attr("width",((w-2*pad)/dataset.length)-3)
    .attr("height",(d)=>(h-yScale(d[2])-pad))
    .attr("fill", function(d){
      return colorScale(d[2])
    })
    .attr("class","bar");
    ...other code used for formatting graph...
});
```

When I run this the errors I get involve parsing the x, y, and height attribute. Using console.log(dataset) prints out the proper values, all stored as objects.

Comment: Your dataset is an array of objects, the headers of the CSV set the keys. But, for the x,y, height, color attributes are treating the dataset as an array of arrays: `d` is an item in the dataset, if it is an object, then you should probably be using `d.year`/`d.crude`/... instead of `d[0]`/`d[1]`/...

Comment: Okay that makes a lot of sense, I just changed the d[0],d[1],... to the d.desired_column and now the data is displaying correctly thanks!

Comment: @J.Hurley, welcome to SO. I hope you find this community very useful and continue your contribution to us with more questions, answers, upvotes, etc. If you had your problem solved, would you mind posting an answer to it and mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dataset is an array of objects, the headers of the CSV set the keys. But, for the x,y, height, color attributes are treating the dataset as an array of arrays: d is an item in the dataset, if it is an object, then you should probably be using d.year/d.crude/... instead of d[0]/d[1]/... – Andrew Reid

I simply had to access the objects with dot notation instead of how you would access a 2D array.